# How to simulate OSPF routing table in Macintosh or Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, networking

I am trying to make a OSPF protocol simulation in Mac or Linux. So, basically I want to run many binary OSPF binaries and they should be able to speak to each other and should be able to use pseudo interface to run OSPF on it. So, if they share the pseudointerface I should be able to assign the same subnet interface on different interfaces.

For example, R1 - OSPF Sim1 has 3 pseudo networking interface. The pseudo networking interface IP is en0 - 192.168.2.1/24 and en1 is 111.111.10.1/24.
The loopback is 1.1.1.1

now, I have R2 - OSPF sim2 has two pseudo networking interface. The pseudo networking interface is en0 - 192.168.2.1/24 and loopback is 2.2.2.2

Now, I have R3 - OSPF sim3 has two pseudo networking interface. The pseudo networking interface is en1 - 111.111.10.2/24 and loopback is 3.3.3.3

I want to simulate in such a way that those are in the subnet can ping each other and rest not. Any idea? Also, I want them to install routes so that kernel is aware of it.

Comment: How about using sockets?

Comment: Use [mininet](http://mininet.org/), you can spin up containers running quagga and scale pretty high since it is using containers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to create three identical linux virtual machines, each one running its own [`quagga`](http://www.quagga.net/) packages.

To do so, I would use Alpine Linux as base (it is a extremely compact and functional linux distribution, which has [`quagga` packages available](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.6/main/x86/quagga)). To create Alpine-based VM, there is a detailed instruction [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Install_Alpine_on_VirtualBox)

There are several examples of OSPF testbeds, [this one](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-build-a-network-of-linux-routers-using-quagga/) seems particularly relevant to what you want to achieve.

Hope it help!